# How to convert a WCF service from SOAP to REST?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

I am very new to WCF and I have questions about it.

After going through some articles I found that in the web.config file if I change the endpoint binding to webHttpBinding from basicHttpBinding and httpGetEnabled from true to false it uses REST.

My question is are these the only two things that I need to change to make a service SOAP or REST? Or do I need to change/add any other things?

Answer (score 6):

You can expose the service in two different endpoints. the `SOAP` one can use the binding that support `SOAP` e.g. `basicHttpBinding`, the `REST`ful one can use the `webHttpBinding`. I assume your `REST` service will be in `JSON`, in that case, you need to configure the two endpoints with the following behaviour configuration

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
    <enableWebScript/>
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

An example of endpoint configuration in your scenario is

```
<services>
  <service name="TestService">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITestService"/>
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="ITestService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Apply `[WebGet]` to the operation contract to make it RESTful. e.g.

```
public interface ITestService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet]
   string HelloWorld(string text)
}
```

SOAP request client endpoint configuration for SOAP service after adding the service reference,

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://www.example.com/soap" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="ITestService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
  </client>
```

in C#

```
TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
client.GetAccount("A123");
```

Comment: And what about httpgetenabled setting it to true or false? I need to change this as well right?