# How to create Restful API's in WCF?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

In WEB API Restful API's are created using ADO.NET and how about WCF?

In WCF if we decorate `WebInvoke(method="POST",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)`
is that same as API structure?

Comment: You may just google about what you want and definitely, you will find a lot of sources, Please take a look at these: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855681/how-to-convert-a-wcf-service-from-soap-to-rest
and
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/590627/Converting-SOAP-based-WCF-Service-to-RESTful-Desig

Comment: WebAPI is not tied to ADO.NET in any shape or fashion.  They are two separate types.

Answer (score 0):

Not only that.
We also need to use the webhttpbinding or webservicehost to host the service.
Here is the web.config(wcf service application)

```
    <services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webbev"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mybehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webbev">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

You can refer to the following document for an example to deepen your understanding. Nothing is better than this.
[Here is official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service)